# primeNG plugin I am using,but i am facing issue like,it is not removing old breadcrumb

Tags: breadcrumbs, primeng

I am using this plugin. But here, the problem is,

```
this.itemBreadcrums.push({ label: 'home', routerLink: ['/home'] });
this.itemBreadcrums.push({ label: 'Participant List', routerLink: ['/home'] 
});
this.itemBreadcrums.push({ label: participantName});
```

In this breadcrumb, when I click on home, other two labels are not hiding.

*https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/angular2-using-breadcrumb-as-angular-service-in-angular-2-application-2/*

Comment: same problem.I check and give u a feedback

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation:

- First solution : you can try to play with shift(), pop(), slice() ... on your MenuItem object to add/delete what you push into it
- Second solution and the best : Try to rebuild breadcrumbs in your "ngOnInit()" function and re-set it to the original point corresponding to the path relied to your component.

  ngOnInit() {
  this.breadcrumbService.setBreadcrumbs("packages.additionalPrices")
  }

This method is the best I've found.